# Why setters are mandatory for fields in a class which reads properties from application.yml file in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot

Following is my code:

Why setter is mandatory. Without it, the class does not
read the property from the
application.yml file
correctly.

Thank you.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class KafkaTopicConfig {

    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Value(value = "${test.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddressFromVariable;
```

Answer (score 1):

From baeldung.com... The Spring framework uses standard Java bean setters, so we must declare setters for each of the properties.

So it looks like you're using Lombok so I would make my class look more like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
@Data
public class KafkaTopicConfig {
    private String bootstrapAddress;
}
```

Then in the main spring boot application class or a `@Configuration` class I would do:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({KafkaTopicConfig.class})
public MyApplicationConfig{
}
```

Then to use my configuration properties I would autowire it into the `@Component` where I wished to use it.

e.g.

```
@Component
public MyComponent{
  private final KafkaTopicConfig config;

  public MyComponent(KafkaTopicConfig config) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  public void doStuff() {
    if ("some address".equals(config.getBootstrapAddress())) {
      blah();
    }
  }

}
```

Using the `@Value` inside the configuration properties feels confusing to me, and defeats the point of using configuration properties in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

should only use @Value in encapsulated components/services (we can call them configuration services).

This way, we will have all our configurations in one place, and that component will only have the responsibility of loading and providing them to other components.

https://stackabuse.com/the-value-annotation-in-spring